# Replacing items in one list from another w/matching names

Tags: r, indexing, lookup-tables

I feel like i've forgotten something very obvious here...

Let's say we have two lists, `a` and `b`, with differing lengths:

```
a <- list(me = "you1", they = "our1", our = "till1", grow = "NOPE1")
b <- list(me = "my2", their = "his2", our = "aft2", new = "noise2", 
          they = "now2", b_names = "thurs2")
```

We want to replace the items in `a` with corresponding items from `b`, **if** an item in `b` has the same name as an item in `a`.

Manually, essentially this would equate to replacing: `me, our, they` in list `a` from those items in list `b`.

For the life of me the only approach i'm coming up with is using `Reduce` rather than `match` or `%chin%` etc, to find the `intersect`ion of names and then always using the last list object as the look-up table. I suppose you really don't need to `Reduce` since `intersect` would work find on it's own.. but regardless...

Isn't there a simpler, more straight forward way that I am simply forgetting?

Here's my code.. it works..but that's not the point.

```
reduce.names <- function(...){
    vars <- list(...)
    if(length(vars) > 2){
        return("only 2 lists allowed...")
    }else {
        Reduce(intersect, Map(names,vars))
    }
}

> matched_names <- reduce.names(a,b)
> matched_names
[1] "me"   "they" "our" 

a[matched_names] <- b[matched_names]
> a
 $me
 [1] "my2"

 $they
 [1] "now2"

 $our
 [1] "aft2"

 $grow
 [1] "NOPE1"
```

here's another approach that works... but just seems redundant and sketchy...

```
> merge(a,b) %>% .[names(a)]
$me
[1] "my2"

$they
[1] "now2"

$our
[1] "aft2"

$grow
[1] "NOPE1"
```

Any advice/alternate approach/reminder of some `base` function I have completely forgotten would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why not just use `intersect` directly? you get a one-liner: `a[intersect(names(a), names(b))] <- b[intersect(names(a), names(b))]`

Comment: agree, I mentioned that above but didn't show the approach. I just feel like I forgot the obvious way to do this... but maybe it's just been that kinda week... Thanks.